# I want to customize default popup on create using redirect new page instead

Tags: isis

On Action create as bellow

```
@Action
public EmployeeVM newEmployee(final String name) {
    employeeRepository.create(name);
    return this;
}
```

It show popup 
[image]
Is it possible to redirect to a new page with the `back button` and `save button` instead of popup.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "back button" or "save button" ... the dialog shows OK and Cancel.  In general, the page that is shown after the action is invoked is that of the returned object (EmployeeVM in this case).  You can also return a java.net.URL which will open up the returned page on a new tab (useful for hyperlinking to other systems, eg a reporting system).

Comment: Back button just like Cancel Button, I call it back button, because it's redirect. for save button just return the the Employee Object, so it will redirect to Employee Page after save. So I use VM now, it work as expected. thank